# Limit points of a line in $\mathbb R^2$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

What is the set of all limit points of any arbitrary line in $\mathbb R^2$?

I think its answer is empty set because if we particularly consider $x$-axis and a point say $(0,2)$ and make  an open ball of radius 1 then that ball will not intersect with $x$-axis. Hence, $x$-axis will have no limit points in $\mathbb R^2$.

Am I correct?

Comment: A line as a continuous function from $[0,1]\to\Bbb R^2$?

Comment: @ZelosMalum:True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $P$ is not on the line than you can take an open ball centred  at $P$ of radius $r$ equal to the half distance of the point from the line. Therefore $P$ is not a limit point of the line.

What happens when this distance is zero, that is the point $P$ is on the line?

Let $P=(x_0,y_0)$ on the line $ax+by=c$ with $a,b$ not both zero. For $n\geq 1$ let $P_n=(x_0+\frac{b}{n},y_0-\frac{a}{n})$, then $P_n$ is on the line, it is different from $P$, and $P_n\to P$.

Hence any point on the line is a [limit point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point).

Comment: :Every nbd of $P$ will have another  point of line other than $P$ itself.Thus,P will become a  limit point of line.

Comment: @Aashiq Raza Yes, see my answer for the details.

Comment: :As mentioned in above comment by Zelos Malum about continuity.Can continuity be helpful in determinig the limit points of sets?How have you made $P_n$?

Comment: @Aashiq Raza You can consider the function $F(x,y)=ax+by$ from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Then the line $F^{-1}(c)$ is a closed set.

Comment: @I got this.So,you are making the use of-If$F:X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous,then for every closed set $B$  of $Y$,thes set $F^{-1}(B)$ is closed in $X$?

Comment: :It is greatly helpful.

Comment: :What about $P_n$?

Comment: @Aashiq Raza $P_n$ is an explicit sequence on the line which tends to $P$. Here I am using the definition of limit point. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point

Comment: :I wanted to learn how to construct such sequences.Is there any general procedure for this?

Comment: @Robert Z I am afraid there is no general procedure.

Comment: :Anyway.thanks a lot

Comment: @Aashiq Raza You are welcome!!